# Django multi-lingual site : how to?

Tags: django, multilingual

I want to have my website in three languages and allow user to change preffered language somewhere in my template. My models will need translating. I found a few libraries perhaps I should use :

https://code.google.com/p/django-multilingual/ for traslating my models

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-localeurl/1.4 for language prefix in URL's

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/ for translating static parts of my site

However I can't understand how these come together. Perhaps someone could give me a rundown of steps to translate my website.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [i18n_patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#django.conf.urls.i18n.i18n_patterns) instead of django-localeurl if you use Django 1.4. or later.

i18n_patterns will set active language based on URL prefix.

Django I18n will serve translated messages in python code and templates based on active language . (You will have to `makemessages` and `compilemessages` to create and compile translations).

For translations in model there are lot of libraries, majority of them use active language to serve field translation. I prefer [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation), which allows translating of 3rd party app models without changing their code.

Hope this helps!